How to use subuidname and subgidname arguments with rootless podman?
Here's a Dockerfile of a GUI app, which builds:
FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim 

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install mousepad -y 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG GROUP_ID=9898
ARG USER_ID=9898

RUN groupadd -g $GROUP_ID --system testpilot && \
    useradd -m --gid $GROUP_ID --system -u $USER_ID testpilot \
    && mkdir -p /home/testpilot/.config \
    && mkdir -p /home/testpilot/.cache \
    && chown --recursive testpilot:testpilot /home/testpilot

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod ugo+x /entrypoint.sh

USER testpilot

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD []


And I run it successfully with the script:
#!/bin/bash
CONTAINER=mousepad
podman run \
    --uidmap=0:1:1 \
    --uidmap=9898:2:1 \
    --rm \
    -it \
    --cgroup-manager systemd \
    --shm-size 100m \
    --net=none \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/.config/Mousepad:/home/testpilot/.config/Mousepad:rw \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/Documents:/home/testpilot/Downloads:rw \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/.local/share/Mousepad:/home/testpilot/.local/share/Mousepad:rw \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    $CONTAINER

My /etc/subuid file looks this:
myuser:100000:65536
And my /etc/subgid file looks the same.
When I run this container, I see UID 100001 in htop, which is what I exaclty wanted. Now, the doc states that This flag conflicts with --userns and --uidmap.
Alright, my file /etc/nsswitch.conf looks this
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
subid:         files


My question is, how must the run script look like in order to use subuidname and subgidname properties instead of using the uidmap?
I'll show you what I have tried:
#!/bin/bash
CONTAINER=mousepad
podman run \
    --subuidname=myuser \
    --subgidname=myuser \
    --rm \
    -it \
    --cgroup-manager systemd \
    --shm-size 100m \
    --net=none \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/.config/Mousepad:/home/testpilot/.config/Mousepad:rw \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/Documents:/home/testpilot/Downloads:rw \
    -v /home/$(whoami)/.local/share/Mousepad:/home/testpilot/.local/share/Mousepad:rw \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    $CONTAINER


which fails consistently with:
Error: potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 100000:100000 for /home/myuser/.local/share/containers/storage/vfs): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid if configured locally and run podman-system-migrate: chown /home/myuser/.local/share/containers/storage/vfs: invalid argument


I've run podman system migrate command million of times, nothing has changed. So, how should the run script look like, if it pleases you?
